# Как уменьшить количество фреймов в секунду?

Tags: python, pygame

Как уменьшить количество фреймов в секунду (т.е. замедлить время)?

Приведенный ниже код не работает:

```py
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(15)
```

Comment: По идее можно создать переменную FPS например, и при выполнении какого то условия в основном цикле менять ее, к примеру уменьшать, если скорость в игре привязана к кадрам, то это поидее уменьшит скорость. `clock.tick(FPS)`

Comment: А что вообще делают ваши две строчки кода, как вы думаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в этом коде 1 ошибка точно есть:

```py
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#^^^^ - с большой буквы

clock.tick(15)
#^^^^ - с маленькой буквы
```

И ещё если это находиться вне игрового цикла, то работать это не будет.

Вот код:

```py
...

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:  # Игровой цикл
    ...
    clock.tick(15)
...
```